# shared_ptr and reference counter

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

In this example I took from the book "Beyond the C++ Standard Library - An introduction to Boost" :

```
boost::shared_ptr<A> createA()
{
boost::shared_ptr<A> p(new B()); // B is a class
return p;
}
int main()
{
typedef std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<A> > container_type;
container.push_back(createA()); /* before returning p does the reference count reach 2 ? */
assert(container[0].use_count() == 1); // true
}
```

I want to know if the reference counter inside "p" can reach a maximum of 2 : 1 when we create the shared pointer "p"  and 2 before destroying "p" after returning (copying) its value...

The goal of my question is to know which option is better when we have a function that returns a shared_ptr : returning a shared_ptr object or a reference to a dynamically created shared_ptr. After testing this :

```
boost::shared_ptr<A>& createA()
{
boost::shared_ptr<A> &p = *(new boost::shared_ptr<A>(new B));
assert(p.use_count() == 1);
return p;
}
/* ... */
boost::shared_ptr<A> & tmp_ref = createA();
assert(tmp_ref.use_count() == 1);
container.push_back(tmp_ref);
assert(container[0].use_count() == 2);
```

I can say that returning an object is preferable because in the other case the ref count is 2 and that's logic (1 because we created the shared_ptr dynamiccaly and 2 because the vector has copied it).

Comment: Copy elision makes it hard to predict. It might or it might not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it could reach 2.

It could reach *higher* than 2 because we don't know how many copies the `vector` implementation may make internally as it's pushing back. It's allowed to copy as many times as it wants.

Comment: Thank you, the goal of my question is to know which option is better when we have a function that returns a shared_ptr : returning an object or its dynamic reference, and after testing this : boost::shared_ptr<A>& createA() { boost::shared_ptr<A> &p = *(new boost::shared_ptr<A>(new B)); assert(p.use_count() == 1); return p;} and then boost::shared_ptr<A> & tmp_ref = createA(); assert(tmp_ref.use_count() == 1); container.push_back(tmp_ref); assert(container[0].use_count() == 2); returning an object is preferable because in the other case the ref count is 2 and that's logic (+1 new +1 vector)

Answer (score 2):

Your second example has a memory leak, so you do not compare apples to apples. Anyway it is definitely cheaper to increase counter rather than create another object on a heap. I do not quite understand why you care about reference counter so much and make decision based if it reaches certain value. Do you understand that if counter reaches 2 it does not make another copy of object 'A'?

Note: for C++11 your function `createA()` should return `std::unique_ptr` instead, which is more effective than `std::shared_ptr` and could be converted to shared if necessary.

Comment: I know, it's a pointer,... if the boost::shared_ptr is dynamically created, the reference count will never reach 0 and so the resource will never be freed after the end of main() => memory leak as you said. I just want a function to fill my vector of shared_ptr<A>, and finally the suitable solution is that the function returns a shared_ptr object, instead of a reference, I'm just curious that's all, I thought that returning a reference is more convenient but it wasn't the case...

Comment: @Aminos don't you see that you call new twice in your second example? does it ring a bell?